# How can my program randomly press a button?

Tags: java, button, random, jframe

I'm trying to make a game where the button would light up and the user would have to press the button in a given time.

Currently, my program has 12 buttons that do something. I'm trying to make it so that these buttons are randomly called by the program. So far, I just have these for 12 buttons that just change the text when pressed by the user.

Now I need a way of making it so that they are randomly pressed the program itself and not the user. Any idea's on how this is done in java?

```
// **** Panels for buttons ****
        JPanel panelButtons = new JPanel();                         // making the panel for the buttons
        panelButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4));               // setting the layout of the buttons to 3x4 as shown above

        b1 = new JButton(" ⃝");                                     // creating button and setting its default text
        b1.setFont(fontText);                                       // setting the font
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){                  // action listener to do something when pressed
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    sendMessage(user + "1" );                       // sends the name of the user that pressed the button and which button
                    String field1 = b1.getText();                   // gets the text from the button and stores it in a String
                    if(field1 == " ⃝"){                             // checks if the string is equal to an empty circle
                        b1.setText("⬤");                            // if true then change to a full circle
                    }
                    else if (field1 == "⬤"){                        // opposite of the above if statement
                        b1.setText(" ⃝");
                    }   
            }
        }); 
        panelButtons.add(b1);                                       // adding the button to the panel

        b2 = new JButton(" ⃝");                                     // creating button and setting its default text
        b2.setFont(fontText);                                       // setting the font
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){                  // action listener to do something when pressed
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
                    sendMessage(user + "2" );                       // sends the name of the user that pressed the button and which button
                    String field2 = b2.getText();                   // gets the text from the button and stores it in a String
                    if(field2 == " ⃝"){                             // checks if the string is equal to an empty circle
                        b2.setText("⬤");                            // if true then change to a full circle
                    }
                    else if (field2 == "⬤"){                        // opposite of the above if statement
                        b2.setText(" ⃝");
                    }   
            }
        });
        panelButtons.add(b2);                                       // adding the button to the panel
```

Comment: Generate a random number from 1 to 12, make a case switch and then trigger the actions the button performs based on the case.

Comment: @CeilingGecko Bad idea. What happens next week when he needs 14 buttons. Or 8? Every time the number changes, you have to update the switch statement. Quite annoying and error prone.

Comment: @EddyG Your point has merit, but to be fair in a real world scenario such major design changes should not happen that often. (Unless intended) And compromises between maintainability and readability should be made, in this case since we do not see the whole picture it might be difficult to assuredly say which option would be the better one in the long run.

Comment: @CeilingGecko I think the real world is exactly the place where fundamental requirements are changing far too often. Probably it is a question of personal style - but I think that "compromise", "readability", and esp. "maintainability" tend to **not** go well with "switch"; especially when other options (like using a list) can be implemented in a straight forward way.

Comment: `field == " "` isn't how you compare `String`'s in Java by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list that holds your button. Use the random number generator to create a random number within the length of the list. Use that (random) index to modify the corresponding button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your twelve buttons in an ordered collection.
2. Put your twelve corresponding actions in another ordered collection in form of a `Consumer<JButton>'(use`Callable`(and ignore the return) or just create something like that if you are not using java 8).
3. Perform a mapping from the Button collection to the action collection.
4. Create a class implementing `ActionListener` like this:

   ```
   private static class Listener implements ActionListener{
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           button2action.get((JButton)e.getSource()).accept(a);
       }
   }
   ```
5. pick up a random element from the value set of the map if you want to get random button pressed.

   ```
   int randomIndex = new random().nextInt(button2action.entrySet().size());
   Iterator<Entry<JButton, Consumer<JButton>>> iter = button2action.entrySet().iterator();
   for (int i = 0; i < randomIndex; i++){
       Entry<JButton, Consumer<JButton>> entry = iter.next();
   }
   entry.getValue().accept(entry.getKey());
   ```
6. add new button action pairs to the map if you want to add new buttons.